# A word similar to "self-promoting"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word (other than *asshole*) to describe someone who always says things in a way that makes other people look incompetent in order to make themselves look better? A different word to describe their language would also suffice.

**Edit:** for clarification, here are a few sentences they might use:

"*I* wouldn't have done it that way"
"Do you even know what you're talking about?" (Implying that they do and you don't.)
"Well, it wouldn't have happened if you knew about such and such."

Basically a kind of blame-passing system to cover up the fact that they are the actual problem.

Comment: 'egotist' is similar, also 'self-serving'

Comment: An egotist is someone who may exhibit this behaviour but the main point is they put people down to make themselves look better.

Comment: There are many words that describe this and participants hit on most.  I would observe that all your examples show arrogance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-righteous maybe the word you're looking for.
According to Oxford Dictionary Self-Righteous means "Having or characterized by a certainty, especially an unfounded one, that one is totally correct or morally superior".

Answer (score 1):

[Know-it-all](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/know-it-all?s=t)

> A person who acts as though he or she knows everything and who
>   dismisses the opinions, comments, or suggestions of others.

Another word that may or may not fit into your context, would be [*cocky*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cocky)

> Arrogant; pertly self-assertive; conceited:

Comment: I've clarified the question, sorry it wasn't that clear.

Answer (score 1):

Condescending, perhaps? 
Seems to fit the sentences.

"howing that you believe you are more intelligent or better than other people."

Merriam Webster
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condescending

Comment: Alex - welcome to the site. **Condescending** was exactly the word I was thinking of. However, links to references supporting your position are normally expected on this site. For this answer I would suggest it could be improved by 1. a definition of *condescending*, 2. a link to where you got this definition from.

Comment: Hello--I was active for a while back but I haven't been on lately. Are definitions expected usually?

Comment: yes. [http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "Links to external resources are encouraged [...] Always quote the most relevant part of an important link"

Comment: Ah. Oh dear. I guess my not taking time to read guides is coming back to bite me in the a**. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Hah - noone actually reads the guides. I picked up my understanding from other people's comments. Finding that link for you was the first time I read the guide...

Answer (score 1):

Pretentious

> Claiming or demanding a position of distinction or merit, especially when unjustified.